# Алгоритмы на графах (путь с max пропускной способностью)

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Доброго времени суток, сообщество.

Я уже довольно долгое время ищу алгоритмы для поиска в графе пути с наибольшей пропускной способностью. Но то ли я не умею пользоваться поисковиком, то ли нет какого-либо понятного ресурса, в общем не смог найти.

Знает кто из обитателей данного ресурса какие, собственно, есть алгоритмы и где о них можно почитать?

Определенно это Дейкстра. Может Флойда-Уоршелла. Но опять таки, мне нужны модификации под данную задачу.

Comment: Для diraria. Насколько я знаю, это не задача о максимальном потоке. Мне нужно найти один путь, но чтобы минимальный вес ребра в таком пути был максимальный.

Comment: У вас фиксированы стартовая и конечная вершины?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ писался в предположении фиксированности стартовой и конечной вершин, то есть задачи `single source single target`.

Мы хотим найти путь в графе с наибольшей пропускной способностью, то есть такой путь, что минимальный вес ребра в нём максимален. Возможное решение:

- Рассматриваем рёбра в порядке убывания (для этого придётся их предварительно отсортировать).
- Пусть сейчас рассматривается ребро веса `w`. Рассмотрим граф, образованный рёбрами веса `>= w`. Обозначим этот граф за `G(w)`. Если в этом графе есть путь из стартовой вершины в конечную, то можно завершать рассмотрение рёбер, этот путь является ответом.
- Осталось понять, как быстро определять, есть ли в графе `G(w)` путь из стартовой вершины в конечную, то есть принадлежат ли стартовая и конечная вершины одной компоненте связности. В этом нам поможет структура данных [`система непересекающихся множеств`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2) (вот ещё описания: [e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/dsu), [викиконспекты](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%9D%D0%9C_(%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2))).
- В качестве непересекающихся множеств будут выступать компоненты связности графа `G(w)`, поэтому СНМ позволит быстро определять, принадлежат ли две вершины одной компоненте связности.
- При рассмотрении каждого ребра мы будем проверять, соединяет ли это ребро разные компоненты связности, если да, то будем объединять эти компоненты в СНМ. Также при каждом рассмотрении будем проверять, принадлежат ли стартовая и конечная вершины одной компоненте связности, если да, то заканчиваем рассмотрение рёбер и переходим к нахождению пути.
- Итак, мы узнали вес искомого пути `w_ans`. Найти сам путь можно любым алгоритмом поиска пути в графе `G(w_ans)`, если рассматривать этот граф как неориентированный. Например, подойдёт [поиск в глубину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83).

Асимптотика алгоритма составляет `O(число_рёбер * log(число_рёбер))` — из-за сортировки рёбер в начале. Все операции в СНМ работают значительно быстрее.

Comment: Благодарю вас за время и за этот алгоритм, но есть ли у него название? Я пишу кое-какую работу и в ней нужно соблюсти формальности.

Comment: @СтаниславСергеев Хороший вопрос. Может и есть, но я его, к сожалению, не знаю.